# Is there a Latin phrase (which can be used in English) for "as per convention"?

Tags: phrase-requests, latin

I want to say something in an academic setting to the effect of "as expected" or "as per convention", when dealing with repeated lists of things with expected formatting. Is there a Latin phrase that an English intellectual would under stand that conveys this?

Comment: If you can predict the following parts, the Latin is _et seq_ meaning 'and the following'.

Comment: Not sure I follow your drift. The standard "et cetera" functions quite well as shorthand for a detailed list of, say, items which you need to refer to perhaps two or more times in some connected writing. Instead of saying "blue, red, green, chartreuse, violet, brown, tan, orange, and mauve" twice (or more), you can say "blue, red, et cetera." I have a feeling that's not what you're after. Let me check my extensive list of legal expressions in Latin, and I might just get back to you.

Comment: As in a replacement for "as per custom" in this sentence "as per custom, I have kept all of your icecream cold"

Comment: One recommendation is to avoid ever using *as* in front of *per*: just say *per* alone, not **as per*.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you'd want to use this? It can be real or made up.

Comment: As in "You should wear a hat to the party as would be expected in this kind of situation"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on the context in which you want to use this, but consider "***pro-forma***":

[Wikipedia describes *pro-forma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_forma) thus:

> *The term **pro forma** (Latin for "**as a matter of form"** or "**for the sake of form**") is most often used to describe a practice or document that is provided as a courtesy and/or satisfies minimum requirements, conforms to a norm or doctrine, tends to be performed perfunctorily and/or is considered a formality.*